# Изображение из base64

Tags: python, tkinter

По сокету получаю изображение в виде base64. Нужно его перекодировать в изображение и вывести на экране через tkinter.

Подскажите, как перекодировать в изображение и как выводить `*.jpeg` изображения в `tkinter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фигвам -- индейская национальная изба. По докам, в PhotoImage можно использовать форматы .gif, .pgm, .ppm. В книге не написано, но base64-кодированный gif оно проглотило (вместо параметра file -- п. data). Так что преобразуйте (ну хотя бы imagemagick'ом -- утилита convert) в один из этих форматов